# How to control thread execution in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

Below python function executes after every 30 seconds, I would like to stop the thread execution after 1 hour (60 minutes) of total time. How can I get this ?  Or polling is better than this ?

```
import time, threading
import datetime

def hold():
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    threading.Timer(30, hold).start()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
    hold()
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you are repeatedly creating threads for this, instead of having a single/main thread that ``time.sleep``s for the delay? Have you tried anything so far? Seeing how this is an uncommon solution to delays in the first place and a naive solution would be straight forward, do you have other constraints not mentioned in the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply make use of the `time` module to do that in the following way

```
import time, threading
import datetime

def hold():

    start = time.time()
    
    while 1:

        print(datetime.datetime.now())
        
        # Sleep for 30 secs
        time.sleep(30)

        # Check if 1 hr over since the start of thread execution
        end = time.time()
        
        # Check if 1 hr passed
        if(end - start >= 3600):
            print(datetime.datetime.now())
            break



if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    # Initiating the thread
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=hold)
    thread1.start()
    thread1.join()
    print("Thread execution complete")
```